# Модульная сетка bootstrap-3

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Как в  bootstrap-3, сделать модульную сетку, которая бы была не фиксированной ширины, а расчитывалась в процентах от ширины экрана, допустим  100% от размера ширины экрана.

Я делаю так, но ширина фиксированная. То есть если уменьшать размер ширины браузера, то блок не будет адаптироваться под эту ширину, и будет появляться ползунок для прокрутки страницы по ширине.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="build/lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="background-liteblue">
                .col-md-6
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="background-red">
                .col-md-6
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: судя по содержанию тегов div Ваши классы должны быть class="col-md-6". На малых и сверх малых разрешениях они расположаться один над другим на всю ширину экрана

Comment: @totorro - но все равно при уменьшении ширины браузера, div элементы  не адаптируются по ширине браузера. Они расположены один около другого, на большом экране. Но не в этом вопрос. Вопрос в том что модульная сетка не адаптируется по проценту от ширины экрана. Она имеет фиксированную ширину.

Comment: это странное поведение, так быть не должно. у вас точно нигде не переопределены классы? background-red и background-liteblue тут нет фиксированной ширины?

Comment: действительно, неполная картина

Comment: и еще вопрос для уверенности. с путями к файлам все ок?

Comment: @Alexey Kopantsev Спасибо, ребят. Оказалось что это было из-за импорта 960 Grid System, которую я сегодня тестировал.

Comment: @totorro Спасибо за поддержку. Я проблему в ответе описал.

Comment: нормально) раз тестируешь, попробуй Susy подключить, ты же все равно через Галп собираешь. если компас подключал, она с ним будет работать, а если нет, то через Bower. Мне если и нужна сетка, то я только сьюзи юзаю

Comment: @AlexeyKopantsev - Интересненько, спасибо) Сейчас взгляну. А в чем её преимущество перед  bootstrap-3?

Comment: она на основе SASS, поэтому подключать в HEAD ничего не надо -> меньше запросов к серверу, более гибкая и ее не надо кастомизировать, не нужно будет засорять хтмл кучей кол-мд-6 и т.д.

Comment: @Alexey Kopantsev хм...  похоже что она и вправду лучше bootstrap-3. Придется её завтра по подробнее посмотреть, а то до утра не усну)

Answer (score 1):

Это поведение было из-за библиотеки от которой мне пришлось отказаться - **960 Grid System**
Может кто знает, актуальна ли она сейчас. Я так понял что , нет. Ну хотелось бы в идеале увидеть отклик.

```
 <!--960 Grid System
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="build/lib/960-Grid-System-master/960-Grid-System-master/code/css/min/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="build/lib/960-Grid-System-master/960-Grid-System-master/code/css/min/text.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="build/lib/960-Grid-System-master/960-Grid-System-master/code/css/min/960.css" />
```

Comment: она работает, по крайней мере, но бутстрап - мейнстрим